# Identify this connector (external 12V christmas tree lights)

Tags: connector, identification

Can anyone help me identify this connector?
[image: Cable with connector to be identified]

(image from Digitec/Galaxus [here](https://www.digitec.ch/en/s1/product/fascinating-lights-wega-extension-cable-christmas-lights-9239777))

It appears to be a 3 pin external (some degree of waterproofing) connector marketed as for "Christmas lights" but in this case used for other exterior lights. What I actually want to buy is an extension cable, or more precisely [this extension cable](https://www.digitec.ch/en/s1/product/fascinating-lights-wega-extension-cable-christmas-lights-9239777), to connect a set of lights I have just installed, but Digitec/Galaxus (same people) now tell me that the cable is out of stock indefinitely. The manufacturer of the lights is I believe [STT AG](https://www.stt.swiss/en/) but their web site is less than helpful. Searching for the type of lights "fascinating lights" is unhelpful. I suspect this cable can be bought from someone else for very little money if only I knew what the connector is called.

Note that the description in the digitec page of this being a 220V connector is incorrect. There is a transformer with the light set built into the plug, and the connection is low voltage. So don't get hang up on finding a mains voltage part.

Comment: It looks like a round DIN (European) style locking connector. Search Google for "DIN" round-twist-lock connectors.

Comment: Chinese connector 500 pc  MOQ is what I'd expect. Anyone else $$$   Close to this https://sc02.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1Dz5fbkxz61VjSZFrq6xeLFXaG.jpg

Comment: Don't expect stock. https://www.waterproofplug.com/

Comment: Buy a male & female waterproof connector of better quality and replace.

Comment: I'd replace it were it not for the fact it's moulded into the power supply / transformer thing. I actually have two such problems with different connectors (sigh)

Comment: can you splice the cable to extend it using different connectors or hard-wired?

Comment: I could splice it I guess, but want the result to be waterproof. Currently I am in the mode of "surely a cable for this already exists if only I could find one"